# GetFiles of certain extension and write to spreadsheet C#

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-csv

I'm writing a application that reads Ia directory contents and writes that to a csv file. I'm trying to get a list of certain file extensions from and upload path which contains a csv file and write a list of the filtered extensions to a new csv file.

I cant figure out how to get the filtered csv file written.....

Here's my method.

```
StringBuilder CreateUserFileUploadList(SLDocument document, StringBuilder destroyWorksheet)
        {
            document.SelectWorksheet("User Folder");
            var stats = document.GetWorksheetStatistics();
            var rowcount = stats.EndRowIndex + 1;

            List unwantedExtensions = cblExtensions.Items.Cast().Where(li => li.Selected).Select(li => li.Text).ToList();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbOtherExtensions.Text))
            {
                unwantedExtensions.AddRange(tbOtherExtensions.Text.ToUpper().Split(new char[] { ',', ' ', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            }
            unwantedExtensions.AddRange("EXE,COM,BAT,JS,VBS,PIF,CMD,DLL,OCX,PWL".Split(new char[] { ',', ' ', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

            // new CSV file
            var workSheet = new StringBuilder();

            workSheet.AppendLine("FILEPATH,Client,Matter,LAST MODIFIED DATE,CREATED DATE,CREATED BY,LAST MODIFIED BY,FOLDER,DOCUMENT NAME,Author,Practice Area,Document Type,ACCESS,Keywords - Comments");

            // loop through the directories
            for (int i = 2; i 100 chars, or including TAB / \ : * ? "  |
                    // Folder has folders>500 or has files>1000
                    //TODO: this loops through leaf folders; we need to check intermediate folders to ensure they don't have too many files or folders or a bad name
                    //Took out @"\", 
                    bool invalidFolderName = new string[] { "/", ":", "*", "?", "" }.Any(s => directoryName.Contains(s));
                    if (invalidFolderName || directoryName.Length > 200 || files.Count() > 1000)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INVALID folder: " + directoryName);
                        lblError.Text = lblError.Text + "\r\n" + "INVALID folder: " + directoryName;
                        //TODO: This should cause the WHOLE upload to fail
                    }

                    // build the target folder path
                    string folder;
                    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { tbAuthor.Text };
                    var path = directoryName.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    folder = path.Last();

                    if (path.Count() > 1)
                    {
                        folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetDocumentsFolderPath"].ToString() + tbAuthor.Text + @"\User Folder" + folder;
                        if (folder.Substring(folder.Length - 1, 1) == @"\")
                        {
                            folder = folder.Substring(0, folder.Length - 1);
                        }
                    }

                    // Get the files
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        // Remove unwanted extensions
                        if (!unwantedExtensions.Contains(file.Extension.Replace(".", "").ToUpper()))
                        {
                            var access = file.GetAccessControl();
                            string user = access.GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
                            //TODO: FWIW, fileName (on netdocs) does NOT need to match the name in the original location...
                            string fullName = file.FullName;
                            string fileName = file.Name;
                            // Wrap in quotes if there are any invalid characters
                            if (fullName.IndexOfAny(csvTokens) >= 0)
                            {
                                fullName = "\"" + fullName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
                            }

                            if (fileName.IndexOfAny(csvTokens) >= 0)
                            {
                                fileName = "\"" + fileName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
                            }

                            if (!document.GetCellValueAsString(i, 2).ToUpper().Contains("DESTROY"))
                            {
                                String practiceArea = GetPracticeAreaForClientMatter(document.GetCellValueAsString(i, 2), document.GetCellValueAsString(i, 3));
                                String documentType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileDocumentType"].ToString();

                                // Validate file
                                // Invalid file names (>200 chars, or TAB / \ : * ? "  | 
                                // Invalid file size (>200 MB)
                                bool invalidFileName = new string[] { "/", @"\", ":", "*", "?", "" }.Any(s => file.Name.Contains(s));
                                if (invalidFileName || file.Length > 200000000 || file.Name.Length > 200)
                                {
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INVALID file: " + file.Name);
                                    lblError.Text = lblError.Text + "\r\n" + "INVALID file: " + file.Name;
                                    //TODO: This should cause the WHOLE upload to fail
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    workSheet.AppendLine(
                                    fullName + "," +
                                    document.GetCellValueAsString(i, 2) + "," +
                                    document.GetCellValueAsString(i, 3) + "," +
                                    file.LastWriteTime + "," +
                                    file.CreationTime + "," +
                                    tbAuthor.Text + "," +
                                    tbAuthor.Text + "," +
                                    folder + "," +
                                    fileName + "," +
                                    tbAuthor.Text + "," +
                                    practiceArea + "," +
                                    documentType + "," +
                                    practiceArea + "|V," +
                                    "Imported from Departed Attorney on: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("G"));
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                destroyWorksheet.AppendLine(fullName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. I'm not sure what the actual problem is. No file is generated? It is generated, but with incorrect data? Do you think you could simplify your code to just demonstrate the problem (in other words, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: Found the Answer!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
bool invalidFileName = new string[] { "/", @"\", ":", "*", "?", "" }.Any(s => file.Name.Contains(s));
                        if (document.GetCellValueAsString(i, 2).ToUpper().Contains("DESTROY"))
                        {// Files in folders marked "destroy" are saved elsewhere



                                //destroyWorkSheet.Append(string.Format("{0}", "Directory" + fullName));
                                //destroyWorkSheet.Append(string.Format("{1}", "FileName" + fullName));
                               // destroyWorkSheet.AppendLine("Directory, FileName");
                               // destroyWorkSheet.Append(string.Format("{0},{1}", "Directory", "FileName") + fullName);
                                destroyWorksheet.AppendLine(fullName);
                          }
                        // Validate file for name (less than 200 chars, can't have TAB / \ : * ? "  | ) and size ( less than 200 MB)
                        else if (invalidFileName || file.Length > 200000000 || file.Name.Length > 200)
                        {// This should cause the WHOLE upload to fail
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INVALID file: " + file.Name);
                            lblError.Text = lblError.Text + "\r\n" + "INVALID file: " + file.Name;
                            errorWorksheet.AppendLine("INVALID file: " + file.Name);
                        }
                        else if (unwantedExtensions.Contains(file.Extension.Replace(".", "").ToUpper()))
                        {// Files with unwanted extensions are filtered out
                            filterWorksheet.AppendLine(fullName);
                        }
```